# How do I accept a file upload on Mechanical Turk?

Tags: file, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk, upload

I have a HIT on Mechanical Turk that requires a file upload of an MP3 file.

```
<h2>Upload your file here</h2>
<input type="file" name="audiofile" />
<input type="submit" />
```

When I review the results from my HIT, mechanical turk will give me the filename but no upload path or link to download the file.

[Filename but no file link http://omarish.com/~omar/mturk.png](http://omarish.com/~omar/mturk.png)

How can I download the file that the worker has submitted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to call this method -after- you get the HIT/assignment back:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMturkAPI/2008-08-02/index.html?ApiReference_GetFileUploadURLOperation.html

One thing to be aware of is that the URL is only valid for a short period of time. In other words, once you call GetFileUploadURL you'll need to call that URL to download the file within 60 seconds.